# Python and Selenium - use XPath text() rather than myElement.text?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Using Python and Selenium I want do something like this:

```
myList = elementList[0].find_elements_by_xpath("/some/xpath")
textValue = myList[0].find_elements_by_xpath("text()[1]")
```

(In the end, both steps will be in nested for-loops)

But the second line crashes:

```
Expected an element or WindowProxy, got: [object Text] {}
```

The obvious suggestion would be to use Selenium's built in function `.text` (like `myList[0].text`) but it is unsuitable in my case since the first (but only that) element in `myList` has two text values and `.text` concatenates them into one string.

So how do I "apply" the XPath function `text()[1]` on an element in `myList` to get that element's text value?

Update: I got an idea. If I add `text()` to the first line of code in my question it works. I interpret that as that `text()` needs to be at the end of a proper XPath? Am I right?

Wouldn't it be possible to use some generic wildcard XPath on my second line since there is only one element there anyway and there is no risk for ambiguity? Something like `textValue = myList[0].find_elements_by_xpath("*/text()[1]")`?

Comment: can you share html?

Comment: @KajalKundu The HTML is very extensive and secret so I prefer not to do that. What do you need to know?

Comment: @KajalKundu I want to loop through all elements in myList and get the **first** text value of each such element using text()[1].

Comment: If you could post that html part only that would help to know if there any other way OP can sort this out.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DebanjanB I am trying to scrape data from a table. It is pretty straightforward with one exception, the first cell has two divs and one span in it (three levels deep) and the deepest div (same level as the span) has a text value in it. Using Selenium for Python's text concatenate that text value with the "main value" of the cell and I am only interested in the main value. One solution I have figured should work is to use XPath's text() combined with [1] because all other cells only have one value, the "main" value, but as you can see, I can't use text() on its own on an element.

Comment: @d-b Was your question answered or you are still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 0):

`myList[0].find_elements_by_xpath("text()[1]")` will return a WebElement array, if anything, not a string of text.  Have you tried either of the following? I think they should work...

```
myList[0].get_attribute(‘text’)
```

Or

```
myList[0].get_attribute(‘innerHTML’)
```

Let me know if you’re able to try those and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Finally I end-up writing two methods in python. One to fetch only the parent text content (child text not included) and the other one to fetch content based on text node position.

Note: If you want to use these methods in other languages, make sure to update the `driver.execute_script` and 'strip()` as per your language. (used the strip() to trim the return value).

**Method 1: get_text_exclude_children(element)**

#parameter - element

#return - element text only (children text will be excluded)

```
def get_text_exclude_children(element):
    return driver.execute_script(
        """
        var parent = arguments[0];
        var child = parent.firstChild;
        var textValue = "";
        while(child) {
            if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
                textValue += child.textContent;
                child = child.nextSibling;
        }
        return textValue;""",
        element).strip()
```

**Method 2: get_text_from_parent_by_position(element,textPostion)**

#parameter - element

#parameter - textPostion (starts with 1, specify the index of the text node to return)

#return - parent text specified at the position

```
def get_text_from_parent_by_position(element,textPosition=1):
    return driver.execute_script(
        """ var parent = arguments[0];
            var textPosition = arguments[1];
            var txtPosition = 0;
            var child = parent.firstChild;
            var textValue="";
            while(child) {
              if (child.nodeType === 3){                        
                if (txtPosition===(textPosition-1)){
                  textValue = child.textContent;                
                  break;
                }}else{txtPosition+=1;}
              child = child.nextSibling;
            }
        return textValue;""",
        element,textPosition).strip()
```

## How to use these methods

```
myList = elementList[0].find_elements_by_xpath("/some/xpath")
listElement = myList[0]
onlyParentText = get_text_exclude_children(listElement)
onlyFirstTextNode = get_text_from_parent_by_position(listElement,1)
print("only parent text: " + onlyParentText)
print("First TextNode text: " + onlyFirstTextNode)
```

Comment: `myList` being an array of elements, I think you mean to pass in `myList[0]`?  Also a couple of typos: missing an 'i' in 'position' when defining `get_text_from_parent_by_postion`; and in the body of that function you've got `txtPosition=+1;`  which I think will just set the variable to 1, you probably meant to use `txtPosition += 1;`?

Comment: @C.Peck Thanks for spotting the typos and list. I think it's time to bed, after a long day. Updated the answer. Did you get a chance to validate these method at your end? (I know you are not OP but just wanted second pair of eyes) :-)

Comment: Still have `{txtPosition=+1;}` :), otherwise the syntax looks good.  I'm a little confused though why `get_text_exclude_children` seems to do the opposite?  Looking at `var child = parent.firstChild;
        var textValue = "";
        while(child) {
            if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
                textValue += child.textContent;
                child = child.nextSibling;
        }
        return textValue;`, it seems like it is returning a concatenation of the text from each child element that has some?

Comment: `{txtPosition=+1;}` is working code, so I don't want to change  it before bed :-). And coming to the logic, yes - I am concatenating all child nodes if the node type is text (kind of filter). By this way, I am ignoring all other children.

Comment: You mean to just set `txtPosition` to 1 rather than adding 1 to whatever it is? Because the former is what I get when I execute that syntax.  If that's what you want the + is a bit confusing, why not just `txtPosition = 1;`

Comment: `txtPosition=+1` is increment, so that I can get the required text node. For eg: if you want the 4th text node then I have to skip 3 text nodes and then capture the 4th one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190745/discussion-between-supputuri-and-c-peck).

Comment: That's what I thought you wanted, and in my IDE that syntax simply sets the value to 1.  ie if I define `var x = 7`, on the next line do `x=+1`, then simply print x to the console, it prints `1`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will test it this weekend. Just a question about a different method to attack the problem. If I add text() to the first line of code in my question it works. I interpret that as that text() need to be at the end of a proper XPath. Wouldn't it be possible to use some generic wildcard XPath on my second line since there is only one element there anyway and there is no risk for ambiguity? Something like `textValue = myList[0].find_elements_by_xpath("*/text()[1]")` ?